# How to use android device as host to pull logs from another android device?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Usually we use windows/linux machines to pull logcat info from an android device.
Is it possible to use android tablet/phone to act as host and get the logs from another android phone connected to it?

Comment: This is both explicitly on-topic as a development tool question, and answerably narrow, as most of the capability is built into modern versions of android (technically, the question isn't even "how?" but rather "is it possible?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. The host Android device needs to be defined as a USB host. Then, once a connection is established, all of the same commands can be run, assuming that ADB is installed on the host device.

See here for more discussion on USB Host Mode support and compatible cables: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support

It is useful to have a terminal program, such as [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en) to issue commands from, and using [busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) to provide additional commands would also be beneficial.

ADB comes as part of the [AOSP](https://source.android.com/) source, so it a device is based off AOSP, then it will possibly include ADB. ADB source is located in [/system/core/adb](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb) in the AOSP source tree.

Here is an example of a session where a Nitrogen6X (host) running a custom AOSP is used to connect to a Galaxy S3 cellphone (client). Note the use of Busybox and ADB, both of which are installed on the host. Busybox also happens to be installed on the client, but this is not necessary:

[image: ADB session Android to Android]

Thus in order to pull logs, just use regular ADB commands (e.g. to copy files), or run logcat, as indicated below:

[image: Running logcat on Android connected to another Android]

Comment: Thanks. Looks like from that link, I will need to find OTG cable first since USB diagnostics failed using a normal cable. I confirmed adb runs on my device using terminal.

Comment: You're welcome. For what it's worth, it's possible to have the *same* Android device serve as both a host and a client at the same time.